# CoreData Optimization Issue (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have `Car` and `Style` models with many-to-many relationships and I have option to filter cars by styles they have. So I use predicate like this:

```
    var subpredicates: [NSPredicate] = []

    let ids: Set<NSManagedObjectID> = // Get ids of Styles

    for id in ids {
        subpredicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "ANY styles == %@", id))
    }

    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subpredicates)
```

And then use it to get count:

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Car>(entityName: "Car")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let count = (try? context.count(for: fetchRequest)) ?? 0
```

The problem occurs when styles count become more then 11. It is took 1 second to filter 12 styles, 3 seconds to filter 13 styles, 9 seconds to filter 14 styles, 25 seconds to filter 15 styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with SUBQUERY:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(styles, $S, $S IN %@).@count > 0", id)
```

This avoids using ANY, which means you can use IN rather than the compound predicate.  This should be more efficient both in parsing the predicate string and in the execution of the fetch, but whether it will actually run any more quickly, I leave to you to test.